# users command lists 5 of the same users...Is this normal?

Tags: command-line, users

So if I type `users` from the CLI

it lists:

user user user user user

If I recall correctly, I've never had that many.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each terminal or SSH login adds another entry to the users list. So if you are 'user' you probably have another four terminals opened and/or SSH sessions.

Comment: OMG, I never knew that, but D'uh!!!! That makes so much sense.

Comment: Maybe you should note that each login shell is added. As some terminal emulators may run multiple tabs in one login shell and thus be added only once.

Answer (score 1):

We do a normal login to system

as well as we also open peudo terminals

or even login from another consoles

or even use remote ssh logins as mentioned in previous answer

So when we issue users command the number of user names shown is equal to all normal login and pseudo terminal or consoles open in ownerhip of same users.

you can try the command `who` to see exactly and know different places from where you have logged in with same user.

And yes this is default behavior so do not worry

Comment: Yes, `who` helps answer a bit of this followup I just posted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115029/what-is-each-logged-in-user-doing