# What is each logged in user doing?

Tags: command-line, users

To expand on this question: [users command lists 5 of the same users...Is this normal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115023/users-command-lists-5-of-the-same-users-what-are-they-doing)

How can I track down what each user is doing or what service/app/request spawned another login of that user?

EDIT: https://askubuntu.com/a/115028/38901 answer from the previous post offers the solution of using `who` which is useful to see *where* the user is. Still, any way to see *what*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `who` command to see where your users have logged in
eg. tty, pseudo terminals, etc.

you can also use

```
ps -ef
```

from your terminal to see what all users are doing

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll mark as solved when the time is allowed. Just a quick question: I see how I can use `ps -ef` and `who` together to know who's doing what, but when there is a `?` under the TTY field, what am I to make of that? Is that the default logged in user?

Answer (score 10):

The `w` command displays exactly that:

```
w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.
```

Example:

```
w
 14:20:15 up  5:10,  4 users,  load average: 0,00, 0,04, 0,05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     pts/2    :0.0             09:11    5:07m  1.02s  1.02s ssh somewhere
user     pts/3    :0.0             09:11    5:08m  2.61s  2.61s ssh somewhere
user     pts/5    :0.0             09:12    5:07m  0.41s  0.41s /usr/bin/luit -
user     pts/0    :0.0             12:35    0.00s  0.34s  0.00s w
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `ps -efu user`, doing `man ps` will list all options avaiable

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -f U $USER
```

will show you the logged in user activity. You can replace the `$USER` with any user id or username. Please note you can't use it in conjunction with the `-f` option as incorrectly stated above.

Comment: The command you stated as being incorrectly stated works fine for me!